# When using "ng generate library" what is an Angular "Library"?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

The Angular CLI has a command

```
ng generate library
```

What does "library" refer to in that context. The [official docs on the `ng generate library` command](https://angular.io/cli/generate#library) don't say much on what a "Library" is or where I can find information on it and the term is so vague that it's difficult to find information with Google.

---

I am tagging this `angular` and not just `angular-cli` because the term is obviously a proper term that I'm not seeing explained in the [official docs](https://angular.io/cli/generate#library). I know what a *library* is. I don't know what an *"Angular Library"* is.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

An ["angular library"](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) in this context refers to self-contained Angular project that stands by itself in the `projects/` directory,

An [Angular Library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) is summarized as,

> Many applications need to solve the same general problems, such as presenting a unified user interface, presenting data, and allowing data entry. Developers can create general solutions for particular domains that can be adapted for re-use in different apps. Such a solution can be built as Angular libraries and these libraries can be published and shared as npm packages.

You can see the files generated here,

```
CREATE projects/foobar/README.md (987 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/karma.conf.js (975 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/ng-package.json (155 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/package.json (136 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/tsconfig.lib.json (726 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/tsconfig.spec.json (246 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/tslint.json (247 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/src/public_api.ts (155 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/src/test.ts (700 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/src/lib/foobar.module.ts (224 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/src/lib/foobar.component.spec.ts (628 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/src/lib/foobar.component.ts (256 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/src/lib/foobar.service.spec.ts (333 bytes)
CREATE projects/foobar/src/lib/foobar.service.ts (135 bytes)
UPDATE angular.json (4855 bytes)
UPDATE package.json (1432 bytes)
UPDATE tsconfig.json (557 bytes)
```

This is added as a requirement to your own project. The idea is to allow you to package components for reuse and the command simply sets up a component in the [Angular Package Format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview#!). The command [`ng generate library` seems to be introduced in the CLI version 6.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/267532d1f26b9a52b80f46e3f16b4afe6497fc00#diff-e48dd98a684a0739ac3f3f82c26876ba)

Note it's not quite the same as a new project, from the docs

> An Angular library is an Angular project that differs from an app in that it **cannot run on its own.** A library must be imported and used in an app.

## See Also

- [`ng-packagr`](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr)
- [Slideshow Introducing Features in Angular 6](http://ng-packagr.github.io/ng-packagr/#slide=1)
- [Creating Angular Libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)
- [Angular Libraries](https://angular.io/guide/libraries)

Answer (score 0):

An Angular library is a functionality that you created and that can be reused in other Angular applications: i.e you developed a markdown WYSIWYG editor and you want to share it, so you bundle all your components, directives, services, pipes etc. into a library that you can publish in the NPM registry.